# TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null React

Tags: reactjs, null, typeerror, src

I am having an issue with an image id being recognized.
In my Home component I use the

document.getElementById("flower-of-life-image").src="./images/flower-of-life.png

several times but for a reason that I cannot grasp in the other functions there is no error message, only in this one:

```
function handleClick() { 
    if (document.getElementById("flower-of-life-image").src="./images/flower-of-life.png"){
        return document.getElementById("flower-of-life-image").src="./images/Krishna-Hara-logo.png";
    }
}
```

The other functions where I use this are:

```
    function scrollMore() {
    scroll.scrollMore(1036);
    elementIsClicked = true;
    if (elementIsClicked  === true) {
        document.getElementById("flower-of-life-image").src="./images/Krishna-Hara-logo.png";
    }
}
```

and another function :

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= 1036) {
        // you're at the bottom of the page
        document.getElementById("flower-of-life-image").src="./images/Krishna-Hara-logo.png";
    } else if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) <= 1036){
        document.getElementById("flower-of-life-image").src="./images/flower-of-life.png";
    }
};
```

Both no error message whatsoever.

The function scrollMore is used on a Link tag:

```
 <Link
    to="/"
    onClick={scrollMore}
 >
```

The function handleClick, the one that doesn't work is in a Link tag as well :

```
<Link to="/krishnahara" id="menu-el" onclick={handleClick()}>
```

Actually, there are 7  tags like this one with different window location pathnames on which I apply the handleClick() fonction.

I am stuck, and have tried to fix this all day.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you inspect the DOM in your browser's dev tools and found an image with this exact `id="flower-of-life-image"` property ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `document.getElementById` (or `.querySelector` etc.) when using React; use element refs instead.

Comment: @JulienD Thanks for the quick answer, I did inspect the DOM and found and image with that id

Comment: @AKX Thank you, I just created a ref for the image with useRef. When I write : flowerOfLifeImgRef.src="./images/flower-of-life.png" I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot add property src, object is not extensible" & when I write : flowerOfLifeImgRef.current.src="./images/flower-of-life.png" I get: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined"

Comment: @ana_m `flowerOfLifeImgRef.current` could be `undefined`; you'll need to do `if(flowerOfLifeImgRef.current) flowerOfLifeImgRef.current.src = ...`

Comment: @AKX Thank you very much!! It worked with if(flowerOfLifeImgRef.current)